# how do I pass ' [single quote character] as argument in linux [bash shell]?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I've `abc.py` file which accepts argument `-p [password]` & `-c [command]`.
Now I can run this file as follows :

```
./abc.py -p 'a!s!d!f' -c 'ifconfig'
```

`a!s!d!f` is my password. As password contains `!` character, so I have to send it as argument in `'  '`. I tried to send it in `"   "` but didn't work.

Now I want to run this code as follows :

```
./abc.py -p 'a!s!d!f' -c './abc.py -p 'a!s!d!f' -c 'ifconfig''
```

I'm giving `./abc.py -p 'a!s!d!f' -c 'ifconfig'` as a argument to `abc.py`

The problem is, I'm unable to send `'` characher as an argument to `abc.py`

I need this `'` character to be sent as input.

I tried using `\` escape character as:

```
./abc.py -p 'a!s!d!f' -c './abc.py -p \'a!s!d!f\' -c \'ifconfig\''
```

But not working. How do I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not a python problem; this is a *shell quoting* problem.

Comment: (In tcsh, even your first example doesn't work).

Comment: it is giving error : -bash: !: event not found
My script executes linux command on another VM using paramiko SSH package.

Comment: So, there is NO SOLUTION to do this? :-(

Comment: Of course there's a solution. It's a bit impatient to expect one in under 10 minutes when your question didn't even say which shell you're using or what error message you got... (And this probably belongs on superuser anyway)

Comment: Actually, `./abc.py -p 'a!s!d!f' -c './abc.py -p "asdf" -c "ifconfig"'` works fine. [the password doesn't contains ! character]. but because of the ! character, I'm facing issues. [Error output : -bash: !: event not found]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash (which follows the [POSIX shell standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_02)), single quotes preserve every character literally, which means there is no way to escape contents within single quotes. Your choices are:

1. Concatenate differently-quoted strings by placing them next to each other:

   ```
   ./abc.py -c "./abc.py -p '"'a!s!d!f'"' -c 'ifconfig'"
   ```
2. Use double-quotes and escape the `!` characters:

   ```
   ./abc.py -c "./abcy.py -p 'a\!s\!d\!f' -c 'ifconfig'"
   ```

Comment: Your first method worked brother... Really thanks..! :-)
I've only 18 reputation points. if there is any way to transfer it to you then tell me.. Would happily do it..  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote both `'` and `!`:

```
./abc.py -p 'a!s!d!f' -c "./abc.py -p 'a!s!d!f' -c 'ifconfig'"

$ cat p.py
import sys
print sys.argv
```

In Korn shell:

```
$ python p.py -p 'a!s!d!f' -c "./abc.py -p 'a!s!d!f' -c 'ifconfig'"
['p.py', '-p', 'a!s!d!f', '-c', "./abc.py -p 'a!s!d!f' -c 'ifconfig'"]
```

In bash `!` is not treated specially only if enclosed in single quotes, so it can be done like this:

```
$ python p.py -p 'a!s!d!f' -c './abc.py -p '"'"'a!s!d!f'"'"' -c config'
['p.py', '-p', 'a!s!d!f', '-c', "./abc.py -p 'a!s!d!f' -c config"]
```

Notice that the result is different then when you quote the whole string with double quotes:

```
$ python p.py -c "./abcy.py -p 'a\!s\!d\!f' -c 'ifconfig'"
['p.py', '-c', "./abcy.py -p 'a\\!s\\!d\\!f' -c 'ifconfig'"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I just tried your suggestion, but is giving me following error :
"-bash: !: event not found".

Comment: I was running it in Korn shell, I'll check to see why it's wrong in bash

Comment: Added answer for bash. I don't really use bash, I always use ksh, so maybe there is a simpler way of quoting strings with spaces, single quotes and exclamation marks, but I don't know it. Anyway, the combination of single and double quotes works.

Comment: You are absolutely right dear.. Thanks for making efforts to answer this. :-)